# How to Draw 3D Synthesis of Fourier Series

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft, matplotlib-3d

I saw this by using Tikz:
https://tikz.net/fourier_series/

I want to create this 3D synthesis of Fourier Series:
[image: 1]

with Python 3D plot, there is matplotlib that is able to do that.

My MWE / What I have achieved is:

```
# https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter24.02-Discrete-Fourier-Transform.html

#  Generate 3 sine waves with frequencies 1 Hz, 4 Hz, and 7 Hz, 
# amplitudes 3, 1 and 0.5, and phase all zeros. 
# Add this 3 sine waves together with a sampling rate 100 Hz

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')

# sampling rate
sr = 100
# sampling interval
ts = 1.0/sr
t = np.arange(0,1,ts)

freq = 1.
x = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
x1 = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 4
x += np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
x2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 7   
x += 0.5* np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
x3 = 0.5* np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

# Write a function DFT(x) which takes in one argument, 
# x - input 1 dimensional real-valued signal. 
# The function will calculate the DFT of the signal and return the DFT values. 

def DFT(x):
    """
    Function to calculate the 
    discrete Fourier Transform 
    of a 1D real-valued signal x
    """

    N = len(x)
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = n.reshape((N, 1))
    e = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    
    X = np.dot(e, x)
    
    return X

X = DFT(x)

# calculate the frequency
N = len(X)
n = np.arange(N)
T = N/sr
freq = n/T 

n_oneside = N//2
# get the one side frequency
f_oneside = freq[:n_oneside]

# normalize the amplitude
X_oneside =X[:n_oneside]/n_oneside

# subplot(2, 2, 3)), the axes will go to the third section of the 2x2 matrix 
# i.e, to the bottom-left corner.
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 6))
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, x, 'r')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.stem(f_oneside, abs(X_oneside), 'b', \
         markerfmt=" ", basefmt="-b")
plt.xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('DFT Amplitude |X(freq)|')
plt.xlim(0, 10)

plt.subplot(3, 2, 5)
plt.plot(t, x1, 'g')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 6)
plt.plot(t, x2, 'g')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: 2]

The plot is still separated in 2D each of them.

1. The single sine wave
2. The Fourier Series (the sum of all the sine waves form number 1)
3. The DFT plot

it is not in 3D, so I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Python Programming and Numerical Methods - A Guide for Engineers and Scientists: Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)](https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter24.02-Discrete-Fourier-Transform.html)

```py
#  Generate 3 sine waves with frequencies 1 Hz, 4 Hz, and 7 Hz, 
# amplitudes 3, 1 and 0.5, and phase all zeros. 
# Add this 3 sine waves together with a sampling rate 100 Hz

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')

# sampling rate
sr = 100
# sampling interval
ts = 1.0/sr
t = np.arange(0,1,ts)

freq = 1.
x = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 4
x += np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

freq = 7   
x += 0.5* np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

# Write a function DFT(x) which takes in one argument, 
# x - input 1 dimensional real-valued signal. 
# The function will calculate the DFT of the signal and return the DFT values. 

def DFT(x):
    """
    Function to calculate the 
    discrete Fourier Transform 
    of a 1D real-valued signal x
    """

    N = len(x)
    n = np.arange(N)
    k = n.reshape((N, 1))
    e = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k * n / N)
    
    X = np.dot(e, x)
    
    return X

X = DFT(x)

# calculate the frequency
N = len(X)
n = np.arange(N)
T = N/sr
freq = n/T 

n_oneside = N//10
# get the one side frequency
f_oneside = freq[:n_oneside]

# normalize the amplitude
X_oneside =X[:n_oneside]/n_oneside

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Plot a sin curve using the x and y axes.
x1 = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
x2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)
x3 = 0.5* np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*t)

# The axis direction for the zs. 
# This is useful when plotting 2D data on a 3D Axes. 
# The data must be passed as xs, ys. 
# Setting zdir to 'y' then plots the data to the x-z-plane.

#ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.plot(t, x, zs=-1, zdir='y', label='DFT(x)')
ax.plot(t, x2, zs=4, zdir='y', label='$\sin (2πt)$')
ax.plot(t, x1, zs=1, zdir='y', label='$3 \sin (2πt)$')
ax.plot(t, x3, zs=7, zdir='y', label='$0.5 \sin (2πt)$')

x4 = [1.2] * n_oneside # Create array of 2 with length of 10
y4 = f_oneside
z4 = abs(X_oneside)
ax.stem(x4, y4, z4, basefmt="-b", label='DFT Amplitude |X(freq)|')

ax.set_title('Discrete Fourier Transform')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=[-0.51, 0.5])

ax.set_xlabel('Time domain', fontweight='bold', fontsize=10, labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency domain', fontweight='bold', fontsize=10, labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel('Amplitude', fontweight='bold', fontsize=10, labelpad=20)
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-35)

plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

Comment: plot method is correct, but the frequency curves and labels are wrong. They're supposed to look as the curves in the question.